# How to add or remove icons from joomla control panel?

Tags: joomla, backend

I would like to add some links to the first panel that displays in Joomla back-end. Which files should I modify?

Comment: You should write it as answer, when you found solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual file path that you need to edit is this:

your-site-root/administrator/modules/mod_quickicon/helper.php

You will see the function getButtons() with an array being created with all the icons and it's params (link, image, text, access). Just copy one, paste it where you want it to show in relevance to the other icons and then replace the content with your content you want added.

Answer (score 0):

The module that is responsible for start control panel you can find in administrator modules - mod_quickicon.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Joomla 2.5 you can also write plug-ins to add icons. Look at the two quickicon plug-ins that come with Joomla.